# get phone number in android

Tags: android

I use this code to get phone no in android2.1.but i don't suceed please help me

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    String contactId,name,number;
    Cursor cursor=getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,null,null,null,null); 

    cursor.moveToFirst();

    if(cursor.moveToFirst())
    {
        do
        {
             contactId=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
                name=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
                number=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Phone.NUMBER));
                int type=cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(Phone.TYPE));

                switch(type)
                {
                case Phone.TYPE_HOME :
                    Toast.makeText(this,"home--"+number+"",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    break;

                case Phone.TYPE_MOBILE :
                    Toast.makeText(this,"mobile--"+number+"",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    break;
                }
            //Toast.makeText(this,"ID--"+contactId+"name"+name+"number:"+number, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }while(cursor.moveToNext());
    }

    // Cursor phone=getContentResolver().query(Phone.CONTENT_URI,null,Phone.CONTACT_ID+"="+contactId,null,null);

    //phone.close();
    cursor.close();
}
```

Comment: Do you encounter an error? We need a little more information to help you out.

Comment: no i haven't any error.the variable take null only...please help me

Answer (score 0):

http://www.androidsnippets.com/get-my-phone-number

```
    private String getPhoneNumber(){
            TelephonyManager __TelephonyManager;
            __TelephonyManager = (TelephonyManager)getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE); 
            return mTelephonyMgr.getLine1Number();
    }
```